# how to find empty catch blocks in java with regex

Tags: java, regex, log4j2

I am working on a big project which has thousand of Java Files. What i have to do is replace all the info level logging in catch block with error level. here is and example method.

```
public static String maskNoToLast4(String number) {

        StringBuffer prepared = new StringBuffer("");

        try {
            number = number.trim();
            return "*" + number.substring(number.length() - 4, number.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LGR.info("Error While last four digits of card", e);
        }
        return prepared.toString();
    }
```

is there a way to find all the catch blocks in which LGR.info() method is being called?

Comment: Title is a bit misleading

Comment: Some IDE provide a regex search tool. So you just need to write your regex to find every `catch(...){LGR.info` and replace those by a `catch(...){LGR.error`. But that's all I can say from this. PS : Be sure that every overloading of `LGR.info` match the overloading of `LGR.error` or you could end up with a LOT of compilation error

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether it's an empty catch block or not.

An empty catch block would be something like:

```
.*(catch\w?(.?)\w*{\w*})
```

where \w is the switch for whitespaces characters. This essentially grabs you everything like: catch (...) {}, however it does not allow something within the {} braces.

I suspect though that you want to auto-replace the info to severe. Let's better not assume that the logger is always called LGR though, then we get

```
.*catch\w?(.?)\w*{.*\.(info).*}.*
```

That way you get any catch (like above, which contains anything, then .info and then anything again. The RegExp will return info as match-group.